# jQuery DataTables : Header error

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables V 1.9.4. This is my html code.

```
<table id="file_list" class="file_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="rowBorder">File</th>
            <th class="rowBorder">Date</th>
            <th class="rowBorder">Size</th>
            <th class="rowBorder">Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This is my js code for initializing datatable.

```
oTable = $('#file_list').dataTable(
        {
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "bAutoWidth": false,

            }
        );
```

My problem is datatable header appears twice. How to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: can u show js import statements

Comment: <script type="text/JavaScript"
 src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
 
 <script class="jsbin"
 src="jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>             <script type="text/JavaScript"
 src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code and it is working as expected. Try doing what I have done

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var oTable;
        oTable = $('#file_list').dataTable(
        {
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
        });
    });
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="listbiew" data-role="content"> 
    <table id="file_list" class="file_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="rowBorder">File</th>
                <th class="rowBorder">Date</th>
                <th class="rowBorder">Size</th>
                <th class="rowBorder">Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```